# Windows Phone developer unlocked key lost after upgrade

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have for more than 1.5 years a WP device which until a few days ago was running Windows Phone 7.5. The device was developer unlocked (process done through AppaMundi as at the time developers in Cyprus didn't have direct access to marketplace), but apparently after the system upgrade to 7.8 done a few days ago, the registration key somehow got lost.
I am currently not able to run and test my apps from Visual Studio on the device as it doesn't recognize it anymore as developer unlocked!

Did anybody heard of any similar issues or maybe even ran into this?
Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Andrei

Answer (score 1):

Blocking usually happens only when the phone "phones home" and finds out that it's unlocked when it shouldn't be. That shouldn't happen when the phone is unlocked legally.

Do you already publish your apps through [dev.windowsphone.com](http://dev.windowsphone.com/)? If so, you can re-unlock your phone easily:

1. Go to Start -> All Programs -> Windows Phone SDK -> run Developer Registration;
2. Connect the phone and run Zune;
3. Enter login credentials to your MS developer account.
4. Click Register and wait a few seconds.

If you still publish apps through AppaMundi, you must request them to do the unlock again for you. That might cost you some additional money.

Comment: Hello @Paulos... only now I saw your answer (sorry)! The problem was solved rather simple: I didn't realize at that moment that 1 year passed since my phone was unlocked, so the key expired...